# Can you make an app interact with instagram in background?

Tags: ios, instagram-api

Is it possible to create an app in xcode that, when browsing the instagram app, can run in the background and cause changes in the instagram app itself? Is something like this available in the instagram API? I can't seem to find it but I'm kind of a beginner so yeah. Basically the app would induce changes in the instagram app itself while you're using instagram. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this for iOS or macOS?

Comment: For starters it's only for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a quite successful Android app using Instagram official API's .
There are no such API's exposed by Instagram . 
Moreover Instagram API's have become much more strict after Facebook Acquisition.